# Is there a way to get an implicit manifest to a trait

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to implement a trait that overrides an Actor to intercept a certain message type as follows:

```
trait MyTrait[M] extends Actor {

    abstract override def receive = {

            case msg: M => 
                // Do Something
                super.receive(msg)
        }
    }
```

Which gives me the compiler warning:

```
abstract type pattern M is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

And I cannot pass an implicit class manifest as it is a trait and not a class. Is there any way of achieving the above while still using a trait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an abstract definition to your trait and implement it later:

```
scala> trait T[A] {
    implicit def ev: Manifest[A]
    def r: Any => Int = { case a: A => 1 case _ => 0}
  }
defined trait T

scala> class X(implicit val ev: Manifest[String]) extends T[String]
defined class X

scala> new X().r("")
res0: Int = 1

scala> new X().r(5)
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: And if want to instantiate it anonymously given a previously defined class? So in the above example I have class SomeActor extends Actor. And I want to create an object using the trait as a mixin: "val x = new SomeActor with MyTrait[String]"

Comment: Well, you can do `val x = new SomeActor with MyTrait[String] {implicit val ev: Manifest[String] = manifest[String] }`